# Linux installation error related to file system

Tags: linux, debian, boot, system-installation, devuan

Installing Devuan Linux (Debian derivative), I get this error message:

> The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in /dev/nvme0n1p1 at /boot/efi failed.

During the installation, I did not specify to create a vfat file system (the SSD was empty), and I did not specify to create the EFI partition under boot/.

This is the SSD required partitioning structure:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1 - 1.0 TB Unknown

  1 MB  FREE SPACE
 98 MB  ESP    EFI
 50 GB  ext4   /      /
 10 GB  ext4   var    /var
 68 GB  swap   swap   swap
  4 GB  ext4   tmp    /tmp
 50 GB  ext4   opt    /opt
500 GB  btrfs  home   /home
342 GB  FREE SPACE
```

I have not been able to get rid of the first 1 MB block of free space, but that should not be the problem.

The system is configured to use UEFI.

- Do I need to add a /boot partition?
- Do I need to add an ESP partition?
- Is a 98 MB size EFI partition enough?

  - Does its size depend on the number of operating systems installed?

How can I fix my system?

Comment: Debian tag: Questions specific to the Debian official distribution (stable, testing, or unstable); if you are using a derivative of Debian (e.g. Mint, Ubuntu, Kali, etc), then use that distribution’s tag instead.

Comment: Please identify the SBC board and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my manual partitioning did not work, I selected automatic partitioning.

The EFI partition was automatically set as bootable, I deleted the ext4 /home partition, I added a new ext4 /opt and a btrfs /home partition.

Everything seems to be going on well now..